# Pakistani wanted for a crime wants asylum in Austria

Tags: austria, refugees

My friend is living in Austria. He is wanted in Pakistan because he committed a murder. He wants asylum in Austria. Would the government there let him stay legally, or they would it deport him? Would he qualify as an asylum seeker or not?

Comment: Umm - typically the basis for seeking asylum in another country is that you fear *unjust* persecution in your own country. If your *friend* committed a murder then any consequences he faces in Pakistan are surely perfectly just and deserved. So no, unless there's something else to this story he's not very likely to be granted asylum in Austria or anywhere else.

Comment: I did a bit of an edit to make your question clearer; apologies if I have misunderstood. You can use the edit to change if needed. You said your friend is living in Austria. Does he actually have a visa/permit to live there, or did he go there on a visit visa and now want to apply for asylum?

Comment: @brhans Most civilized countries, including Austria, do not extradite criminals if they risk capital punishment, which is probably the case here. Unworthy conditions in penal institutions may be considered a violation of basic human rights and is also an argument often preventing extraditions.

Answer (score 10):

Austria does have a bilateral [extradition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Austria%E2%80%93Pakistan_relations) treaty with Pakistan. So the likely answer is yes, they would probably send him back (and not just deport him, but put him in shackles and send him back as a prisoner for the Pakistani authorities to take).

That being said, before Austria extradites your friend, it's likely to demand the promise from Pakistan that the death penalty be taken off the table.

Also, if your friend was unfairly persecuted for some reason, and if the murder was committed in self-defense, perhaps, there is a chance of asylum, but since we really do not know anything about his case, any kind of speculation, without having such information, would be futile on our part.

Comment: Thank you for answer .. and i wanna ask something more if you know which european country is best for him that can give him legal stay there because he dont want to go back in pakistan if he will go they will kill to him

Comment: @MubarakSaith, Without giving us more details about the killing, what you're asking us is impossible to answer. Some countries will go above and beyond to protect their own nationals, but if the person is not already a citizen, that person is unlikely to be protected at all. Normally people flee to South America, not Europe if they want to avoid extradition. And even then, even in South America, murderers are usually not welcomed unless they happen to be extremely wealthy.

Comment: @MubarakSaith, If your friend is less than 39 years and 6 months old, he could join the French Foreign Legion. If he survives the Legion, he'll then be given a totally brand new identity and French citizenship. Many murderers choose the French Foreign Legion option. It gives them a second chance.